# Anonymous submission form

Tags: php, forms

im looking for a script much like the one used on [Saxton Hale Facts](http://www.saxtonhalefacts.net), can anybody point my in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Plan your requirements (What do you want to save)
- Design a database that meets your requirements.
- Build a form that can handle all above
- Store submitted data
- Display it

Comment: @ fabrik -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnomes_%28South_Park%29

Comment: @Andrew: I've never seen an episode :o Thank you. :)